# kworker is running modprobe every second

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel

Using `fatrace`, I discovered that on my computer, `modprobe` runs approximately every second.  To find out why, I replaced `modprobe` temporarily with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "$0" "$@" > /tmp/asdf
echo >> /tmp/asdf
echo $PPID >> /tmp/asdf
```

This showed me that modprobe is being invoked as

```
/sbin/modprobe -q -- multi-user
```

which didn't turn up any relevant hits on Google.

The parent process is always `[kworker/u48:2]`.  How can I find out what's causing this?

Comment: Which distro are you using? On the systems I have access to, the `multi-user` option does not exist at all.

Comment: I'm running Arch Linux

Comment: `multi-user` is not an option name here, by the way. It follows [after `--`, which explicitly ends the options part of a command invocation](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean-also-known-as-bare-double-dash). Only positional parameters follow, in this case: `[ modulename ] [ module parameters... ]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14949678/502399) StackOverflow answer, I determined that `ifplugd` was ultimately responsible for the `modprobe` invocations.  `ps` showed that

```
root       883  0.0  0.0   6292  1128 ?        S    Dec01   2:34 /usr/bin/ifplugd -i multi-user -fwI -u0 -d10
```

was running, probably explaining the weird `multi-user` argument in the `modprobe` invocations.  I ran

```
# systemctl stop ifplugd@multi-user
# systemctl disable ifplugd@multi-user
# fatrace
```

and confirmed that `modprobe` is no longer being repeatedly executed.

Answer (score 0):

- Watch uevents:

  ```
  udevadm monitor
  ```
- Make sure the old way of autoloading modules is disabled:

  ```
  sudo sysctl kernel.hotplug=""
  ```

Comment: Thanks!  But `udevadm monitor` just sits there, and the `sysctl` command prints `sysctl: malformed setting "kernel.hotplug="`.